# ModuleNotFoundError after making a setup.py and running "pip install -e ."

Tags: python

I am trying to import the classes SqlQuery, SqlPost, and SqlPage *to* the file `Query.py` *from* the file "database.py" with the path "C:\Users\myName\dir1\2020\Indeed-Scraper\database\database.py". My first attempt at this was to use relative imports: `from ...database.database import SqlQuery` which I presumed would work since the "database" folder is up two levels from `Query.py`. Not so. That returned `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

I posted about this on StackOverflow and a helpful user suggested this fix: "make a `setup.py` for your project. Then run `pip install -e`".

Well I tried that. I now have a `setup.py` folder in the root directory of my project that looks like this:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="indeedscraper",
    version="0.1.1",
    author="myName",
    author_email="myName@provider.com",
    description="A tool used to scrape & display data from Indeed",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/myUsername/myProject",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

And I ran `pip install -e .` in the root directory of my project. Now PyCharm autocompletes "`from in`" to "`from indeedscraper`", so something changed. But `from indeedscraper.database.database import SqlQuery` still gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myName/dir1/2020/Indeed-Scraper/scraper/classes/Query.py", line 17, in <module>
    from indeedscraper.database.database import SqlQuery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indeedscraper'
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed? I'm kind of stuck here learning to make a package and import from that package, because the alternative is to copy ~50 lines of code from my "database.py" file, which is ugly.

Edit: I do have `__init__.py` files in my top level dir, "database.py", and the directory housing the file I am trying to import into. Like this:

```
project_name/
    __init__.py
    database/
        __init__.py
        database.py
    scraper/
        __init__.py # I do have this file here, sorry, didn't realize it was important
        classes/
            __init__.py
            Query.py
```

Edit2: I realize the problem may be stemming from the fact that I am using Anaconda. I import in Query.py right, but the first 2 lines of my output in PyCharm read: "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs\august_2019_django_project\python.exe C:/Users/myname/dir1/2020/Indeed-Scraper/scraper/classes/Query.py"

Could this be it?

Comment: You might have to add an `__init__.py` file under project_name/scraper

Comment: It's there! I didn't add it because I didn't realize it was important. Edited my OP to include it. Thanks!